# If 1 is not an eigenvalue of A, then $x_n=A^n\left[x_0-\left(I-A\right)^{-1}b\right]+\left(I-A\right)^{-1}b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

Consider a nonhomogeneous linear dynamical system given by $x_{n+1}=Ax_n+b$ and an initial state vector $x_0$. Use the iteration method to show that:
$$x_n=A^nx_0+\left(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}+...+A+I\right)b$$
I understand how to use iteration to find this however it's the next part that I can't figure out:

Then, use if 1 is not an eigenvalue of A, then $$\left(A^k+A^{k-1}+...+A+I\right)=\left(I-A^{k+1}\right)\left(I-A\right)^{-1}$$
to deduce: If 1 is not an eigenvalue of A, then$$x_n=A^n\left[x_0-\left(I-A\right)^{-1}b\right]+\left(I-A\right)^{-1}b$$
Next, suppose that all the eigenvalues of A have magnitude less than 1. Use the previous part to find a formula for $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)$ that does not depend on $x_0$.

Comment: If $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A,$ then $I-A$ is invertible. That's pretty much all that's troubling you.